# Render JSX in Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm looking to familiarize myself with Vue 3 coming from Vue 2 and I was curious if there is a better approach to rendering out JSX in a component?

I saw an example on here like this:

```js
import { ref, computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
    setup() {
        const name = ref<string>('Lily')

        const hello = computed((): string => {
        return `Hello ${name.value}!`;
        }) 

        const render = (): JSX.Element => {
           return <HelloWorld msg={hello.value} />
        }

        return ()=>render();
    },
})
```

However I wasn't the biggest fan of how that return looked. Is this a better/cleaner practice and approach?

```js
import { ref, computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
    setup() {
        const name = ref<string>('Lily')

        const hello = computed((): string => {
        return `Hello ${name.value}!`;
        }) 

        const render = () => (): JSX.Element => {
           return <HelloWorld msg={hello.value} />
        }

        return render();
    },
})
```

Comment: You don't like the render functions? https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#basic-usage

Comment: JSX support in Vue is different than a library like React, I believe the official documentation provided by @kissu is a good starting point for understanding.

Comment: Also, with dynamic components you may not need JSX at all whatsoever. Render functions (and JSX) are usually used for advanced use-cases, seems quite overkill in your case. Vue's syntax is simpler, don't over-engineer it.

Comment: I haven't touched the render functions much, I gravitated toward jsx predominantly because I thought the readability was better over render functions and to help get familiar with using JSX syntax as a skill. You make a valid point about overengineering it, SFC is probably the best approach for me here.

Comment: Also the most common one for sure.